# How do I catch a server code error using Axios

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, axios

I have made a GET request to an API which rejects GET requests with a 400 error (and "Invalid request") response; and while I can catch and handle the response data, there is another error line which I can't catch:

> GET https://**API address**/test 400

My code is as follows:

```
try {
    let res = await this.axios.get(API)
    console.log(res.data)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data)
}
```

I did also try this as a promise chain (with a catch) - but same result and I was thinking that wrapping everything in a try catch would do the trick.

My API code (hosted on Firebase) is as follows:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        if (request.method !== 'POST') {
            return response.status(400).send('Invalid request.')
        }
        response.status(200).send("Hello from Firebase!");
    })
});
```

First line is when I send a POST request, and the rest comes back after the GET request:
[image: console]

How do I handle that GET error? And where is it coming from?

Comment: Hello, I just tested the thing out and try catch works good to me. What line are you missing?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. The blacked out line is just the API address. Not sure what other line you're referring to?

Comment: Can you detail how do you link the URL with `helloWorld` to the Cloud Function named `test`? The HTTPS Cloud Function can be called with https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/test

Comment: Sorry, I had two versions. Edited the first line to remove that discrepancy. This does work fine if I send a POST request, so it's something about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, it seems you are calling the Cloud Function with a wrong URL.

You use

```
 https://us-central1-xxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld
```

as shown in the first version of your question,

when you should use

```
 https://us-central1-xxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/test
```

since your Cloud Function is defined with

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest()
```

You'll find the corresponding doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function

---

**Update following your comment:**

It is normal that GET shows an error since you have the following code:

```
 if (request.method !== 'POST') {
   return response.status(400).send('Invalid request.')
 }
```

Since GET is not a POST you enter this if and get a 400 error...

Comment: Thanks, as I said above, this was an error in my post, not my code. POST works fine, GET continues to show this error.

Comment: It is normal that GET shows a error since you have the following code: `if (request.method !== 'POST') {
            return response.status(400).send('Invalid request.')
        }`. Since GET is not a POST you enter this if and get a 400 error...

Comment: Thanks. So this must be a browser function to record outgoing and throw its own error if the code is 400+ or something?
I tried it on Edge earlier and it was the same, but I have just tried Firefox and that just displayed "Invalid request" as I would have expected.

Comment: Yes, browsers may report the error differently. You should use the Developer options and look at the Network tab for a complete reporting. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_details.